# WM_CLOSE is not arriving at the target window; Spy++ cannot see WM_CLOSE either

Tags: c#, winapi, postmessage

I am trying to send `WM_CLOSE` from my app to a target app to tell it to close. I am running in the VS debugger on NET 6.0.

I find the handle of the target app and send a `WM_CLOSE` message to its handle, but Spy++ says that the message never arrives at the target window, and so of course the target window does not close.

I know I have the right target handle because I can see it in Spy++ (I tag the target window title bar manually with the Spy++ crosshairs), and they match. Also when I get the window title from the handle, it gives the same window title visible in the title bar of the target app. And the return code from the `PostMessage` call is zero, so `PostMessage` is saying that it sent the message.

But neither `PostMessage` nor `SendMessage` sends a message that is visible in the messages for the target window that are being logged in real-time in the Spy++ rolling display.

Why is my `WM_CLOSE` message not: (1) visible in Spy++, and (2) not reaching the target app?

```
public static void
    SendCloseToHandle(IntPtr handle) {
    var result = PostMessage(handle, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    if (result != 0) {
      FormAppendTextContent($"WM_CLOSE failed to send. {result:X}");
      return;
    }

    //SendMessage(handle, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    var title = GetWindowTitle(handle);
    FormAppendTextContent($"Posted WM_CLOSE message to {title} '{handle:X}'");
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *And the return code from the PostMessage call is zero, so PostMessage is saying that it sent the message.*

That's just wrong. The `PostMessage` function [returns zero **on failure**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea). So, assuming your code (as presented) doesn't show the error message, then the `PostMessage` call is failing, and `WM_CLOSE` isn't being sent to the target.

You need to change your error-handling to use `if (result == 0) { ...` and then, in that block, call the `GetLastError` function to retrieve the error code. If that is `5` (as I suspect), then the call is failing due to incorrect UIPI access, and you will need to address that issue as described in this Q/A: [Cross-process PostMessage, UIPI restrictions and UIAccess=”true”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40122964/10871073).

---

Note: Calling the `GetLastError` WinAPI function from C# and/or .Net projects is not trivial; for an in-depth discussion of how to properly do so, see here: [WinApi - GetLastError vs. Marshal.GetLastWin32Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17918266/10871073).

Comment: Wow. That was an *excellent* answer. You were exactly right on all counts. PostMessage returns a bool, not a uint HRESULT with S_OK=0, (which I was assuming, incorrectly). I don't remember where I copied that ```if (result !=0) ``` from; it came with the PostMessage example from somewhere.  And now I understand what's going on with Spy++ and the target app too. THANK YOU. And THANK YOU again for the UIPI link.

Comment: If you are planning to call `GetLastError` make sure your P/Invoke declaration for `PostMessage` has the [`SetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.setlasterror) attribute set to `true`. Otherwise you'll observe spurious results from the .NET marshaler implementation.

Comment: In which case, don't call `GetLastError()` directly, make sure you are using `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`/`Marshal.GetLastPInvokeError()` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah. As also pointed out by IInspectable. I'm no expert in C# or .NET programming, but the basic premises of the WinAPI still apply, and (hopefully) my answer is helpful "as is". I can (of course) add details, and maybe I should. But the answer in my last link is ... let's say ... *reasonable*.

Comment: @Remy See edit. No point in waxing lyrical about an issue that's already been fully addressed. :)