# OleClipboard and IDataObject under local SYSTEM account

Tags: c++, winapi, ole, idataobject

There is an implementation of remote file transfer via dragging virtual files using `IStream`/`IDataObject` (based on Raymond Chen's blog topic: [What a drag: Dragging a virtual file (IStream edition)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080319-00/?p=23073)).

Basically, it works good. But if the application is run under the `SYSTEM` account, the `IDataObject::GetData()` is called only once - requests a `FILEDESCRIPTOR`, but doesn't return with a requests for `FILECONTENTS`.

How I use `IDataObject`:

```
if (SUCCEEDED(OleInitialize(NULL))) {
    IDataObject* dtob = new MyDataObject(/*some files info here*/);
    if (dtob) {
        OleSetClipboard(dtob);
        dtob->Release();
    }
    
    //simulate Ctrl-V
    ...
    
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    OleUninitialize();
}
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40122964/cross-process-postmessage-uipi-restrictions-and-uiaccess-true and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64485600/wm-dropfiles-not-called-on-x64/ that may be related

Comment: Why is your app running as `SYSTEM` to begin with? It really shouldn't be.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, there are some functionality which works only under system, e.g it should work on the lock screen. So, @SimonMourier assumed above that the problem is that higher privileged applications can't receive messages from the lower privileged. But I tried `ChangeWindowMessageFilter` - it doesn't work.

Comment: Here is a similar thread, I suggest you could refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1168537/oleclipboard-and-idataobject-under-local-system-ac  It is the result of some kind of windows security mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set security for the process using `CoInitializeSecurity`:

```
HRESULT res = CoInitialize(NULL);
if (SUCCEEDED(res))
    CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_NONE,
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IDENTIFY, NULL, NULL, NULL);

// your code here....

if (SUCCEEDED(res))
    CoUninitialize();
```